# Share view over view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to design a view for an alert banner at the top of the screen. It will look like a push message banner, but then it'll have my own design.

I want to design this in Storyboard since I heard that programming constrains is a pain in the ass. However, I can only add views to a view controller in storyboard, and my alert view must be available to multiple view controllers. How to design a view that is instantiatable between multiple view controllers? Or do I have to design this another way?

Comment: You should use a view controller which manages your banner view. In particular, it  should manage the insertion and removal of the view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Should the banner view have a viewcontroller on its own? And how can I instantiate the banner view in a second view controller?

Comment: *"I heard that programming constrains is a pain..."* Well, you heard wrong. Once you learn how, it is often ***easier*** than setting them in Storyboard. Regardless, if you want a "Banner" at the top of the screen, you may want to put your Banner view at the top and use a Container View for the rest of the screen... then do your navigation inside that container view. That way your banner is always visible - no need to "share between multiple view controllers."

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/donileo/RMessage

Comment: Yes, it should. You can instantiate this view controller from your storyboard, and it loads the view. Take look at *Implementing a Container View Controller* in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652764, even though your controller is not a container view controller.